# iOS - UIButton setImage in UITableView Not Updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to update button images in my table view. When my table view initially loads, the button images are correct. But when I scroll down the new cells don't update to my new images; they simply reuse a random old image from the initial set. I have tried `setImage` and `setBackgroundImage`. Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        SSKGrooveCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"grooveCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        SSKSongCellInfo *entry = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSArray *icons = [plistHelper iconsForGroove:entry.metadata.title];
        NSString *icon = [icons objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *iconImgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"element_%@_grooves", icon];
        NSString *iconImgWithExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", iconImgString];
        [cell.inst1Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconImgWithExt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.titleLabel.text = entry.metadata.title;
        return cell;
    }
    return  nil;
}
```

Comment: [plistHelper iconsForGroove:entry.metadata.title] <-- does this take longer than 1 second ? like, is that entry being downloaded ?

Comment: That entry is not being downloaded. It's being taken from a local plist.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick test, add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:iconImgWithExt];
```

Do you see correct images?

- If no, check your images and image names
- If yes, check your `inst1Button` IBOutlet connection.

Comment: I see the correct images. I double checked my `inst1Button` IBOutlet connection and it is correct. Any other possible problems?

Comment: Added and connected a UIImageView to my cell. I see the correct images for it. Is this a UIButton issue?

Comment: My test project with UIButton is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue on an app. Turns out there's a bug in iOS 7.1 regarding a UIButton in a UITableView. You need to call setNeedsLayout on the button after you've set the image. E.g.:

```
[cell.inst1Button setNeedsLayout];
```